# I'm looking for a specific Harry Potter Fan-Fiction where the Trio are on the run or wanted

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Here's what I remember from it:

- Harry, Ron, and Hermione are all on the run in their 3<sup>rd</sup> or 5<sup>th</sup> year
- They are innocent or something
- They try to commit suicide by slitting their wrists in their apartment on Christmas (I think) and they are found by an old woman
- There's a sequel to it
- There was a fire that killed the old woman (maybe in the sequel)
- There are more than 10 chapters
- They are powerful
- In the sequel I think they travel to different parts of the world to get stronger

  - Hermione goes to Morocco or somewhere hot and goes in a temple or tomb